# How to delete a file from repository on github.com?

Tags: git, github

How do I delete a file from a repository on github.com ?

I am using git for windows user interface to checkin the files into github repository, but I checked in a wrong readme.rtf file into github.

I don't see a "delete" option anywhere on the github remote repository.

[image: My repository on github]

Answer (score 5):

From GitHub's own [support page](https://help.github.com/articles/deleting-files/):

> Browse to the file in your repository that you want to delete.
>
> At the top of the file, click (trashcan icon).
>
> At the bottom of the page, type a short, meaningful commit message that describes the change you made to the file.
>
> Below the commit message fields, decide whether to add your commit to the current branch or to a new branch. If your current branch is master, you should choose to create a new branch for your commit and then create a pull request.
>
> Click Propose file change.

Step 1 in this list would imply clicking on the file you wish to delete from your screenshot above, so that you're looking at the file itself.

Comment: I don't see any trash icon.

Comment: sorry. I found the icon.

Comment: When looking at the file in question, you should see a row of buttons across the top, like so: http://i.imgur.com/mvnfdJM.png - It is the last icon on the right.

Comment: Thanks much I found it. very kind of you.

Comment: Not a problem - and welcome to StackOverflow! If you found this answer to help you, please consider clicking on the Up arrow next to it to vote for it, and also clicking the Tick to accept it as the answer. Best wishes!

Comment: Thanks Warren. It won't let me click up arrow. It says I need 15 reputations.

Comment: Hi @basam - no problems, you should at least click on the 'Tick' icon to accept the answer, so that this question doesn't remain in the Unanswered queue.

Answer (score 2):

Open a command prompt and navigate to the directory of your project (dir /path/to/your/project/root)

Either copy and paste the correct contents into the existing readme or delete the existing readme and place the new one it its place. Then type the commands:

`git add readme.rtf` (assuming you still called the new one readme.rtf)

`git commit -m "fixed readme"`

`git push`

That should do it.

Comment: thanks much. I am trying to git gui instead of command line interface.

Comment: This is not the right answer, unless you are replacing the file directly with another file named the same thing. If you were doing this, your GUI would handle that operation should you simply rename your new file Readme.rtf and drop it over the old file in WIndows itself.